# how to use global multidimensional arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I tries to use multidimensional global arrays in PHP. Unfortunately, so far I don't know how to do it...

```
   global $datawords;

function unfold_sentence($str)
{
    $sentence_arr = preg_split('/[.?!]/',$str); 
    $i=0;
    foreach ($sentence_arr as $value) {
            $i++;
            $datawords['sentence'][$i]['sentence'] = $value;
            $datawords['sentence'][$i]['words'] = preg_split( '/[-?!.,;: ]+/', $value);
    }
}

unfold_sentence("hello! how are you?");
print_r($datawords['sentence'][1]['sentence']); //empty echo
```

I tried to use **$GLOBALS** - instead of **$datawords** - unsuccessfully.

Comment: You never call `unfold_sentence`, so that code doesn't execute.

Comment: sorry, it's just a selected piece of code, of course it refers to a function. I changed.

Comment: Where do you initialise `$i`?

Comment: I fixed it, but that does not solve the problem of not working arrays...

Comment: Sure, that is why I posted it as a comment; not as an answer. It is important that your question has code that reproduces the issue you are asking about, and not some other error. I have now posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`global` is a keyword that you would use in the function where you want to *reference* the global variable. The [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) gives an example for using the `global` keyword, and states:

> By declaring `$a` and `$b` global ***within the function***, all references to either variable will refer to the global version.

Note that you can have `$i` generated by the `foreach` loop itself.

So it should be:

```
function unfold_sentence($str)
{
    global $datawords;

    $sentence_arr = preg_split('/[.?!]/',$str); 
    foreach ($sentence_arr as $i => $value) {
        $datawords['sentence'][$i]['sentence'] = $value;
        $datawords['sentence'][$i]['words'] = preg_split( '/[-?!.,;: ]+/', $value);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! now everything is clear.